# Why does GCC claim I'm violating "at least one argument for variadic macro" when I have at least one argument?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, gcc-warning

Here is the example code I used to reproduce this error:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD(_1,_2,FUNC_NAME,...) FUNC_NAME

#define TEST_HELLO_IMPL(condition) do{ \
        if(!(condition)) {\
          std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl; \
        }\
      } while(0)

#define TEST_HELLO_MESSAGE_IMPL(condition, message) do{ \
        if(!(condition)) {\
            std::cout << "hello" << message << std::endl; \
        }\
      } while(0)

//Runs during runtime and debug
#define TEST_HELLO(...) TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD(__VA_ARGS__, TEST_HELLO_MESSAGE_IMPL, TEST_HELLO_IMPL)(__VA_ARGS__)


int main()
{
    auto x = 3 * (3);
    TEST_HELLO(x >= 3);
}
```

In godbolt with GCC x86-64 8.2 using:

`-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wpedantic -Werror`

as arguments I get the following error:

```
<source>:24:22: error: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro [-Werror]

 TEST_HELLO(x >= 3);

                  ^

cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

Compiler returned: 1
```

Yet there is clearly at least one argument in the macro.  Now I know this compiles when I don't enable this warning, and when I don't enable this warning as an error, but for other reasons I want to keep these compiler flags (or at least keep the same results).

**Why does GCC claim that I've passed zero arguments when I have not?**

Comment: You’re invoking `TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD` with not enough arguments, not `TEST_HELLO`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually with `TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD`, the error message is slightly misleading.

The macro takes 3 arguments and `...`  , in ISO C++ that means you must pass at least 4 arguments but in fact you only pass 3. (Ref: C++17 [cpp.replace]/4)

The `TEST_HELLO` expands to `TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD(x >= 3, TEST_HELLO_MESSAGE_IMPL, TEST_HELLO_IMPL)(x >= 3)` .

Comment: Ah, so what you are saying is the  `...` in `TEST_2_ARG_MACRO_OVERLOAD` needs a parameter?  I can see that I definitely don't pass anything into there.

Comment: @opa it needs an argument, yes